# Asp button does not fire OnClick event

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I've searched the forums and have yet to find a soln to my specific problem.  I'm writing an asp.net aspx page with

```
<asp:Button ID="Add" OnClick="Add_Click" runat="server" Text="Add" CausesValidation="False"/>
```

where Visual Studio even autofilled my OnClick function, and my VB code behind function looks like this:

```
Protected Sub Add_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Add.Click
    Server.Transfer("TimeReportingAdd.aspx", False)
End Sub
```

I have another page with a button set similarly and it works fine.  Does not even hit event during a debug.  The main page (TimeReporting.aspx) just refreshes on the click and I would like it to redirect to another page (TimeReportingAdd.aspx).  The button was not copied but created new and the event was created by double clicking in the designer.  runat="server" is present in all my content headers etc.  I don't think my TimeReporting.aspx page header needs any validation elements because the page that works doesn't have them.  The Add button is declared as follows in my vb code behind:

```
Protected WithEvents Add As Global.System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button
```

Also, the button that works in another page is easier, doesnt even have onclick or validation:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Query" />

Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
...
End Sub
```

I've tried deleting the button and adding it again multiple times.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: The key is that you said `CausesValidation="False"` which does not call your event. Try changing that to true.

Comment: Thanks, but this didnt affect it

Comment: Do you have a name conflict on the button or event (add is pretty generic)? Is it inside an update panel? Try adding a new button with a new name and make sure that works.

Comment: use OnClick="Add_Click();" then add javascript function too.

Comment: For javascript use OnClientClick, but he shouldn't need that for this.

Comment: Thanks, I've actually created an Add Modify and Delete Button in a row and none of them fire the click event they are handled by

Answer (score 0):

Please remove OnClick="Add_Click". This will fix your problem.

There are two things you need to consider:-

1. When you add OnClick, this means you want to handle click in Java Script.
2. To handle click in server side, you provide a method in code behind with Handles clause.

First approach overrides second one.

Comment: Unfortunately this didnt affect the event either.  Thanks though

Comment: I have just created a project with same code as yours and it is working as expected.

Can you please post your aspx here.

Comment: Thank you, I managed to get it to work with my answer below.  It was posting back to the original page instead of the next page but that property made it work.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this to work by giving this property in my button:

```
PostBackUrl="~/TimeReportingAdd.aspx"
```

It was posting back to the initial page TimeReporting.aspx